# How to retrieve All and Running application sizes, CPU usage programmatically?

Tags: android, storage, cpu-usage, usage-statistics

I am implementing android application for getting **All applications** and **Running applications** 
and their **sizes, usage and CPU usage**.

But i'm only get the all and running applications **Icon, Label and Packegename** not able to 
 retrieve **sizes, usage and CPU usage**.

I saw an application in GooglePlayStore that is **AndroidSystem Info**. In that app all system information given.

I want to retrieve that information programmatically.

Can anyone please help me to get total system information

thanks in advance.................

Here is my code:

**For getting All Applications:**

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);
ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
TextView tvAppName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
TextView tvPkgName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

// set data to display
ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
```

**For Getting Running Applications**

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runAppList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int listsize = runAppList.size();
Log.v("tag", "listsize..." + listsize);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Do this using ***IPackageStatsObserver.aidl*** interface. Create package ***android.content.pm*** in your app src directory and Implement below code  It will return all appliscation size.

```
Method getPackageSizedInfo =pm.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo",String.class,IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizedInfo.invoke(pm, pkgname,new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
@Override 
public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)throws RemoteException {double size=(double)pStats.codeSize+pStats.cacheSize+pStats.dataSize;}
});
```

Comment: (codeSize+dataSize+cacheSize)  will it return totalAppSize or only (codeSize+dataSize)  will return total App Size

Comment: i m successfully finding apps list and its memory size for each app but how can i find cpu usage for each app ?

Comment: @user3233280 : Can you please explain as to how you were able to get the ram and CPU usage for the package as I also have the same requirement in an application. Thanks in advance,